# When to explicitly state types of inputs of functions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, language-concepts

I am able to calculate the mean word length per starting letter for the  spark collection

```
val animals23 = sc.parallelize(List(("a","ant"), ("c","crocodile"), ("c","cheetah"), ("c","cat"), ("d","dolphin"), ("d","dog"), ("g","gnu"), ("l","leopard"), ("l","lion"), ("s","spider"), ("t","tiger"), ("w","whale")), 2)
```

either with

```
animals23.
    aggregateByKey((0,0))(
        (x, y) => (x._1 + y.length, x._2 + 1),
        (x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)
    ).
    map(x => (x._1, x._2._1.toDouble / x._2._2.toDouble)).
    collect
```

or with

```
animals23.
    combineByKey(
        (x:String) => (x.length,1),
        (x:(Int, Int), y:String) => (x._1 + y.length, x._2 + 1),
        (x:(Int, Int), y:(Int, Int)) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)
    ).
    map(x => (x._1, x._2._1.toDouble / x._2._2.toDouble)).
    collect
```

each resulting in

```
Array((a,3.0), (c,6.333333333333333), (d,5.0), (g,3.0), (l,5.5), (w,5.0), (s,6.0), (t,5.0))
```

What I do not understand: Why am I required to explicitly state the types in the functions in the second example while the first example's functions can do without?

I am talking about

```
(x, y) => (x._1 + y.length, x._2 + 1),
(x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)
```

vs

```
(x:(Int, Int), y:String) => (x._1 + y.length, x._2 + 1),
(x:(Int, Int), y:(Int, Int)) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)
```

and it might be more a Scala than a Spark question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am I required to explicitly state the types in the functions in
>   the second example while the first example's functions can do without?

Because in the first example, the compiler is able to infer the type of `seqOp` based on the first argument list supplied. `aggregateByKey` is using [*currying*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/currying.html):

```
def aggregateByKey[U](zeroValue: U)
                     (seqOp: (U, V) ⇒ U, 
                      combOp: (U, U) ⇒ U)
                     (implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[(K, U)]
```

The way [type inference](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/local-type-inference.html) works in Scala, is that the compiler is able to infer the type of the second argument list based on the first. So in the first example, it knows that that `seqOp` is a function `((Int, Int), String) => (Int, Int)`, same goes for `combOp`.

On the contrary, `combineByKey` there's only a single argument list:

```
combineByKey[C](createCombiner: (V) ⇒ C, 
                mergeValue: (C, V) ⇒ C, 
                mergeCombiners: (C, C) ⇒ C): RDD[(K, C)]
```

And without explicitly stating the types, the compiler doesn't know what to infer `x` and `y` to.

What you can do to help the compiler is to explicitly specify the type arguments:

```
animals23
  .combineByKey[(Int, Int)](x => (x.length,1), 
                           (x, y) => (x._1 + y.length, x._2 + 1),
                           (x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))
  .map(x => (x._1, x._2._1.toDouble / x._2._2.toDouble))
  .collect
```

Comment: Couldn't the compiler work out from `animals23` that the `x` of `createCombiner` is a String and thus the result of it (with `x.length`) must be an Int and infer from there the types for the other two functions? How is currying (from the compiler's perspective, not the programmer's) different then a single argument list? I don't see why the compiler has been limited this way.

Comment: @Make42 Theoretically yes, the compiler could infer type `C` from the previous provided function, but that's not how Scala's local type inference works. Type information flows across parameter lists and not within parameter lists. You can read a bit on that in [Programming in Scala](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&pg=PA325&lpg=PA325&dq=curried+type+inference+scala&source=bl&ots=FMrhYEMPmv&sig=jGB32Uu-VTdrJ1hziUOmu-IsPTo&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIu6PW0uTMAhXMJMAKHUYBB5EQ6AEIMzAH#v=onepage&q=curried%20type%20inference%20scala&f=false).

Comment: @Make42 Also see [this ticket](https://issues.scala-lang.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SI-3293) for a rather weak explanation. The usual answer is "it's complicated".

Comment: Well, for now I guess your comment "Type information flows across parameter lists and not within parameter lists." is good enough for me.